# 3-dimensional h-cobordisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $W$ be a $3$-dimensional $h$-cobordism of closed surfaces $M_0$ and $M_1$. Can we prove that $W$ is trivial? That is, $W$ is homeomorphic to $M_0 \times [0,1]$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $M_0=M_1=S^2$, this follows from the 3-dimensional Poincaré conjecture: glueing in 3-balls, you get a simply connected $3$-manifold, that has to be $S^3$, so $W=S^2\times\left[0,1\right]$.

For surfaces of higher genus, the result follows from Waldhausens rigidity theorem, which says that homotopy-equivalent Haken manifolds with homeomorphic boundaries are homeomorphic. (An irreducible $3$-manifold with non-spherical boundary is necessarily a Haken manifold.)

Comment: This is morally correct but there are two points. First is that the result for an irreducible h-cobordism is due to Stallings (On fibering certain 3-manifolds) well before Waldhausen. To show irreducibility one also needs the Poincaré conjecture, proved subsequently by Perelman.

Comment: Does the same conclusion hold if the boundary is $P^2$?

Comment: @Adterram - Yes, this follows from a theorem of Livesay. - https://doi.org/10.2307/1970543 - in that case we get $P \times I$.

Comment: @Adterram - Also, if the answer answers your question, it is polite to accept it - you just tick the tick mark. best